# Grouping Related Constants Shared Between Classes

Tags: java, oop, effective-java

In Effective Java, Item 17, Josh Bloch argues that putting static members into an interface (and implementing that interface) is a bad practice known as the *Constant Interface Antipattern*:

> The constant interface pattern is a poor use of interfaces. That a class
>   uses some constants internally is an
>   implementation detail. **Implementing a
>   constant interface causes this
>   implementation detail to leak into the
>   class's exported API.** It is of no
>   consequence to the users of a class
>   that the class implements a constant
>   interface. In fact, it may even
>   confuse them. Worse, it represents a
>   commitment: if in a future release the
>   class is modified so that it no longer
>   needs to use the constants, it still
>   must implement the interface to ensure
>   binary compatibility. If a nonfinal
>   class implements a constant interface,
>   all of its subclasses will have their
>   namespaces polluted by the constants
>   in the interface.
>
> There are several constant interfaces in the java platform
>   libraries, such as
>   `java.io.ObjectStreamConstants`. These
>   interfaces should be regarded as
>   anomalies and should not be emulated.

I'm pretty confident I understand the reasoning behind this and completely agree.

My question is: is grouping related constants (note: these are NOT suitable for an enum, consider the math example of the related constants pi and e) in an interface versus a non-instantiable class a good idea, **provided you only access the values via static references and static imports, keep the interace hidden from your API w/ a default access modifier, and never actually implement the interface**?

Why or why not?  Are there any advantages are there to grouping them in a class other than being able to use a private constructor to ensure the constant grouping type is never instantiated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's put it the other way. There is no advantage of using interfaces for constants. As you know, interfaces are for defining contracts, not for constants. I don't see the problem of changing the `interface` keyword to `class` keyword and using `public static final` fields for example. Using interfaces for keeping constants is never a good idea. I think people use this anti-pattern because they don't know about static imports(it was introduced in `Java 5.0`) or they are too lazy to dispatch their constants in the appropriate classes. Instead they just create one interface and let every class implement it.

Edit: By the way the question sounds me like - Is it a good idea to watch television, looking at the neighbourhood's TV using a telescope, provided the seeing is good. The answer is simple - no, the telescope is invented for other things. Ah, and I know this example is dumb:)